# Show mouse coordinates in popup div using jquery, following the mouse move

Tags: jquery, html, popup, mousemove, mouse-coordinates

I need to be able to check various elements positions inside a html page. For this I want a div that shows the mouse coordinates as a popup close to the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mouse positioning in jQuery</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
#click{
    background-color:#efefef;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font:1.2em Arial;
    line-height:50px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$(document).click(function(e){ // for click action
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        // e.pageX - gives you X position
        // e.pageY - gives you Y position
        //$('#click').html('e.pageX = ' + e.pageX + ', e.pageY = ' + e.pageY);
        $("#click").css({left:(e.pageX+20) + "px", top:(e.pageY+20) + "px"});
        $('#click').html('e.pageX = ' + e.pageX + ', e.pageY = ' + e.pageY);
        $('#click').show();
        //$('#click').slideToggle(); // for toggle show/hide popup
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
On mouse move...

<div id="click">The cursor position will show in this div.</div>

</body>
</html>
```